# How can I delete elements in a list with the same values ​specified in square brackets?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list and I indexed them myself using "[","]".

As you can see below, some of these elements are duplicated, but their values ​​before the index in square brackets are different.

How can I delete duplicated items from the indexes that I have specified?

```
6557.94172139931[6]
5354.8168281469[9]
5354.81740416957[9]
5760.29235605679[8]
6212.12135703147[7]
4869.7862090936[95]
4869.78639031275[95]
3681.97068695995[10]
3681.9727736492[10]
```

What i want:

```
6557.42618426901[6]
5354.8168281469[9]
5760.29235605679[8]
6212.12135703147[7]
4869.7862090936[95]
3681.97068695995[10]
```

Here is my code that I'm trying to do:

```
IEnumerable<string> matchingList;
foreach (string item in distanceandlayername)
{
    string index = item.Split('[', ']')[1];
    matchingList = distanceandlayername.Where(x => x.Contains($"[{index}]"));

    foreach (string part in matchingList)
    {
        int i = distanceandlayername.IndexOf(index);
        distanceandlayername.RemoveAt(i);
    }
```

Comment: distanceandlayername is a List<T> and the one you want to keep is the first (by listindex) found?

Comment: As you have probably noticed, if you change a list while you are iterating it with a `foreach`, bad things happen.  Consider recording the indexes of the items to remove and make another pass, this time on the list of items to remove (iterating backwards) and remove them from the original list.  By the way, are you getting an error when you try this?  If so, the error should be in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update*

Changes after the revised spec ("please sort it").  I now convert the original line into a (double, int) tuple and work with that.  That allows things to be sorted.

In the end, I format things the way you do originally.  As @ralf says, you should consider having something that not just one weird string.

First create your list of numbers (by the way, this code should be in your question):

```
private static readonly List<string> annotatedNumbers = new List<string>
{
    "6557.94172139931[6]",
    "5354.8168281469[9]",
    "5354.81740416957[9]",
    "5760.29235605679[8]",
    "6212.12135703147[7]",
    "4869.7862090936[95]",
    "4869.78639031275[95]",
    "3681.97068695995[10]",
    "3681.9727736492[10]",
};
```

Then write some code like this.  It accumulates the indexes to remove and then, in a second pass, removes those indexes:

```
public static IEnumerable<(double distance, int layer)> GetTrimmedList(List<string> withDups)
{
    var layerNumbersToCheck = new List<int>();
    var distanceAndLayerNames = new List<(double distance, int layer)>();

    foreach (var item in withDups)
    {
        var parts = item.Split('[', ']');
        if (parts.Length < 2)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Item: {item} incorrectly formatted");
        }
        if (!double.TryParse(parts[0], out var distance))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Distance in item: {item} is not a valid double");
        }
        if (!int.TryParse(parts[1], out var layerNum))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Layer number in item: {item} is not a number");
        }


        if (!layerNumbersToCheck.Contains(layerNum))
        {
            layerNumbersToCheck.Add(layerNum);
            distanceAndLayerNames.Add((distance, layerNum));
        }
    }

    var result = distanceAndLayerNames.OrderBy(item => item.layer);

    return result;
}
```

}

Finally, some code to exercise the function:

```
public static void Test()
{
    var result = GetTrimmedList(annotatedNumbers);
    foreach(var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.distance}[{item.layer}]");
    }
}
```

The result looks like:

```
6557.94172139931[6]
6212.12135703147[7]
5760.29235605679[8]
5354.8168281469[9]
3681.97068695995[10]
4869.7862090936[95]
```

Comment: it works very well, but the result is not of double type as you suggested, it comes like this: `655794172139931[6]
621212135703147[7]
576029235605679[8]
53548168281469[9]
368197068695995[10]
48697862090936[95]`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.  What locale are you (I'm _en-US_ where the decimal point is a dot). If you are in a locale with a comma as a decimal separator, then `6557.94172139931` will parse as `655794172139931`. There are a ton of questions about thos on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might work.

```
for(var i = 0; i < distanceandlayername.Count; i++)
{ 
    var item = distanceandlayername[i];
    string layer = item.Substring(item.IndexOf('['));   
    distanceandlayername.RemoveAll(x=> x!= item && x.Contains(layer));
}
```

If you also might have duplicate distances(so complete identical items) this needs to be adapted.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works very well.

One last thing, how can I sort the elements in this list by index named layer from smallest to largest? @Ralf

Comment: @E.MRZ: That's a second question.  Basically, create a list of anonymous objects that contain the two numeric parts (the double and the int) and then sort that on the int

Comment: @Flydog57 
Could you please make an example?

Comment: @E.MRZ as you also said 'and I indexed them myself using "[","]"' why did you then choose that format in the first place? When you have requirements like sorting having everything in one string is counterproductive. Is there something that prevents you using a class with 2 distinct types?

Comment: @Ralf In fact, the part I added is the layer names of the values ​​I received.
These layer names have an order, this order gets complicated as the list is created automatically.
So I need to sort by layer names from smallest to largest.

Comment: Yes but what prevents you from putting the distances in a class when you receive it that also has a additional layer property and keep them separated in the right type and easily useable?

Comment: @Ralf Frankly, I don't know how to do it.
The lengths come to me automatically and they all have a layer name, so  which element belongs to which layer, I convert it to string value and write the layer name inside square brackets for I don't lose.
In order to use this list properly, I need to sort the layer names in square brackets from smallest to largest.

I'm very new to using c# and I don't know how to do some methods.